# How do I stick my footer to the bottom when there is less content in my html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can someone help me out to figure how to stick my footer to the bottom of my projects page, as it sticks down on other pages but not on this specific projects page, I think it's because it does not have a lot on content in it, I have tries various solutions present on the internet, but none of them have worked yet, so please help me out with this, I really appreciate any help I get.
Here is my html code for my projects page.

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: url(images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  header .header-brand {
    margin: 31px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 38px;
    padding: 0 20px 0 40px;
    float: left;
  }
}

.social-footer {
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 850px;
  background-color: #111;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* display: -webkit-flex; */
  /* display: -ms-flexbox; */
  /* -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center; */
  /* -webkit-justify-content: space-between; */
  /* -ms-flex-pack: justify; */
}

.social-footer .social-footer-icons li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.social-footer .social-footer-icons li:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.social-footer .social-footer-icons .fa {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  color: #fefefe;
}

.social-footer .social-footer-icons .fa:hover {
  color: #4a4a4a;
  transition: color 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Projects</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bg">
    <header>
      <a href="index.html" class="header-brand"><img src="images/default.png" alt="Logo" width="100" , height="70"></a>
      <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar">
          <div class="menu">
            <div class="line line-1"></div>
            <div class="line line-2"></div>
            <div class="line line-3"></div>
          </div>
          <ul class="nav-list">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="about.html" class="nav-link">About Me</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="projects.html" class="nav-link">Projects</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact Me</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Hire Me</li></a>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <section class="projects-links">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <h2>Projects</h2>
          <a href="GoGrocery.html">
            <div class="projects-link">
              <p>GoGrocery</p>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="TalkBoxPro.html">
            <div class="projects-link">
              <p>TalkBox-Pro</p>
            </div>
          </a>
          <!-- <a href="Medico.html"><div class="projects-link"><p>Medi Co.</p></div></a> -->
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="projects-links">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <h2>Under Construction</h2>
          <div class="projects-link">
            <p>Medi Co.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <footer class="social-footer" id="footer">
        <div class="social-footer-icons">
          <ul class="menu simple">
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: There is an example sticky footer in the bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/sticky-footer/

Comment: I tries your example but it doesn't work, I have used bootstrap only for the social media icons and nothing else.